# Small separation between columns

Tags: tables, columns

On the bottom you will find a minimal example of my code (perhaps a little bit too much packages).

My problem is that I would like to have a very small separation between each column. That's why I inserted a column with width 0.01cm, but somehow these columns are way larger.

Did I make a mistake with my definition or is there an easier way?

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    \usepackage{amsmath}    \usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}    \usepackage{pdfpages}    \usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}    \usepackage{pst-pdf}    \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig,rotating,longtable,lscape,geometry,layouts}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}    \usepackage{verbatim} \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}    \usepackage{float,mdwlist,enumerate}    \usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{makecell}    \usepackage{float,mdwlist,enumitem}    \usepackage{siunitx}    \usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand{\muc}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{C{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mucThree}[2]{\multicolumn{3}{C{#1}}{#2}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[h!]    
    \caption{Bereits erbrachte Leistungen}   
    \begin{tabular}{C{1.5cm}|p{0.01cm}|C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}C{1.5cm}C{0.01cm}} 
&&&\mucThree{3cm}{$c_{S_1}=18$} && \mucThree{3cm}{$c_{S_1}=20$} &&\mucThree{3cm}{$c_{S_1}=22$} \\ \cline{3-7} \cline{9-13}           
&& $E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]/E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ 
&& $E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]/E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ &&$E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]$ && $E\left[\pi_R^{c}\right]/E\left[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}\right]$ \\
$c_{S_2}=18$    &&  4208    &&  4364    &&  1,04    &&  3934    &&  4236    &&  1,08    &&  3819    &&  4109    &&  1,08 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use all thouse fixed width columns?  Would a `c` type column not be sufficient as you don't seem to need line breaks in cells. Apart from that, you might want to remove all occurences of `C{0.01cm}` and use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` or anyl other length of your choice (default is 6pt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely too many packages for the example. Note also that

1. `mdwlist` has been unmaintained for more than 20 years
2. loading both `enumitem` and `enumerate` is wrong
3. `pstricks` *and* `tikz`? Are you sure?
4. `letter` is not an option for `article`; it should be `letterpaper` (or omitted, as it's the default)

Now the table: most of the space is eaten up by the headers; since they're repeated, it's better to give them a name and repeat that, with an explanation at the bottom.

I recommend using `siunitx` features and `booktabs`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[h!]    
\caption{Bereits erbrachte Leistungen}   

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  *{3}{
    S[table-format=4.0]
    S[table-format=4.0]
    S[table-format=1.2]
  }
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$c_{S_1}=18$}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$c_{S_1}=20$}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$c_{S_1}=22$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)}
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)}
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} \\
\midrule
$c_{S_2}=18$
& 4208 & 4364 & 1,04 & 3934 & 4236 & 1,08 & 3819 & 4109 & 1,08 \\
$c_{S_2}=18$
& 4208 & 4364 & 1,04 & 3934 & 4236 & 1,08 & 3819 & 4109 & 1,08 \\
$c_{S_2}=18$
& 4208 & 4364 & 1,04 & 3934 & 4236 & 1,08 & 3819 & 4109 & 1,08 \\
$c_{S_2}=18$
& 4208 & 4364 & 1,04 & 3934 & 4236 & 1,08 & 3819 & 4109 & 1,08 \\
$c_{S_2}=18$
& 4208 & 4364 & 1,04 & 3934 & 4236 & 1,08 & 3819 & 4109 & 1,08 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l@{}}{%
  (1): $E[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}]$;\qquad
  (2): $E[\pi_R^{c}]$;\qquad
  (3): $E[\pi_R^{c}]/E[\pi_R^{\bar{c}}]$%
}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]